# How can I implement an outbox delay in an outlook add in?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

In my Outlook Add In I want to implement a callback function that works without Exchange Server. For this purpose all mails, when they are sent, should be moved to the mail outbox for a time selected by the user and only then be sent. In the time the mails are in the outbox, the sending process can be cancelled by the user moving the mail to another folder.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to implement this. But I need the add in for a university project. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [MailItem.DeferredDeliveryTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.deferreddeliverytime) property which sets a `Date` indicating the date and time the mail message is to be delivered.